# NHibernate: How do I XmlSerialize an ISet<T>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, xml-serialization

Given:

- I'm trying to [create a REST API using ASP.NET MVC](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/10/03/create-rest-api-using-asp-net-mvc-that-speaks-both-json-and-plain-xml.aspx).
- I'm using NHibernate in my data access layer.

Problem:

- I'm can't XmlSerialize ISet properties.

I get errors like the following:

> Cannot serialize member
>   [namespace].[entity].[property] of
>   type
>   Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[[namespace].[entity],
>   [assembly], Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>   because it is an interface.

- I'll freely admit: I'm very new to NHibernate.

  - So I don't know what my options are.
- I *believe* that I need to use a set as opposed to a bag because my collections contain unique items.
- When I converted the ISet properties to HashedTable properties (i.e. a concrete class), I got errors like the following:

> You must implement a default accessor
>   on
>   Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet`1[[namespace].[entity],
>   [assembly],
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] because it
>   inherits from ICollection.

My questions:

- What should I do to remedy this situation?

  - Should I implement default accessors in all of my entity classes?

    - If so, is there a recommended pattern for doing so?

As a sidenote, I tried Googling for help.
- I don't think this is a new problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NHibernate serialization [has been treated **a lot** on stackoverflow](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=nhibernate+serialize+site:stackoverflow.com+-detachedcriteria). See:

- [C# Castle ActiveRecord: How to elegantly (XML) serialize ActiveRecord objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539118/c-castle-activerecord-how-to-elegantly-xml-serialize-activerecord-objects)
- [How do I serialize all properties of an NHibernate-mapped object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190718/how-do-i-serialize-all-properties-of-an-nhibernate-mapped-object)
- [NHibernate and WCF Serialization(Unidirectional)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681538/nhibernate-and-wcf-serializationunidirectional)
- [JSON.NET and nHibernate Lazy Loading of Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286721/json-net-and-nhibernate-lazy-loading-of-collections)
- [Which .NET JSON serializers can deal with NHibernate proxy objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918483/which-net-json-serializers-can-deal-with-nhibernate-proxy-objects)
- [DTOs vs Serializing Persisted Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688473/dtos-vs-serializing-persisted-entities)
- [Returning NHibernate mapping classes from WCF services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577201/returning-nhibernate-mapping-classes-from-wcf-services)

**Bottom line: use DTOs.**

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) instead. It's more restrictive, but will serialize more.

[Dan Rigsby explains the difference between XMLSerializer and DataContractSerializer](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/)

Here's an example from one of my posts on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963831/cant-access-element-after-datacontractserializer):

```
public XDocument GetProductXML(Product product)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Product));
        var document = new XDocument();

        using (var writer = document.CreateWriter())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, product);
            writer.Close();
        }

        return document;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can never XML Serialize an interface - only a concrete class that implements the interface.

Comment: I've had to deal with this before. In an XML Serializable class, a List member had to be exposed as a List property, rather than IList or IEnumerable. Otherwise, the interface property would have to be duplicated in a non-interface version. The former choice is the lesser of two evils, I think.

Comment: @Grant: you can't do that with NHibernate. NH needs collections interfaces.

Comment: @Mauricio: OK, very good. I only know the tiniest bit about NH, and I did not know THAT. Hmm, looks like a tough situation then.

Answer (score 0):

1)  Load the Dozer bean mapper from mapping file

```
DozerBeanMapper dtoMapper = new DozerBeanMapper(Arrays.asList(new String[]{dozerMappingfile}));
```

2)   Covert each object to a normal object removing persistentbag related details

```
List<MyEjb>  lstProfilehib =  //hibernate loaded objects
        List<MyEjb>  lstProfile  = new ArrayList<MyEjb>();
        for(MyEjb sp: lstProfilehib){
            lstProfile.add( dtoMapper.map(sp, MyEjb.class)); 
        }
```