# .Net class with NHibernate and XmlSerializer

Tags: nhibernate, xml-serialization

Have a .net class that I want to persist/retrieve to/from Oracle 11g database using NHibernate. Contains an array of objects that NHibernate insists must be the interface type IDictionary, ISet, or IList.  I also need to serialize the class to XML using XmlSerializer, however, XmlSerializer cannot serialize members of type IList (for example) "because it is an interface". Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958684/nhibernate-how-do-i-xmlserialize-an-isett

Answer (score 1):

[NHibernate: How do I XmlSerialize an ISet<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958684/nhibernate-how-do-i-xmlserialize-an-isett)

**Bottom Line: Use DTOs.**