# How to clone objects in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, serialization

How to implement objects (entities) cloning in NHibernate? Each entity class has such properties:

```
public virtual IList<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
```

Also, the entity class inherits BaseObject.
I tried to implement the solution using XML serialization, but it's not possible to serialize interfaces.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AutoMapper http://automapper.codeplex.com/ solves my problem.
For example, it's possible to clone a business object in the next way:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Transaction, Transaction>();
var newtransact = new Transaction();
Mapper.Map(transact, newtransact);
```

Comment: You will want to exclude the Id properties using `Mapper.CreateMap<Transaction, Transaction>().ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.Ignore());` and manually copy IList properties using something like: `newtransact.Clubs = this.Clubs.Select(item => item.Clone()).ToList();` - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396808/

Answer (score 2):

[Use DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958684/nhibernate-how-do-i-xmlserialize-an-isett/1967272#1967272).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of your domain or requirements, nor whether am I misunderstanding your need, but implementing the [ICloneable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) and writing the code to clone your object should work.

Remember you'll have to type cast when cloning.

```
ClonedObject clonedObjectinstance = (ClonedObject)initialEntityInstance.Clone();
```

Comment: Please, tell me where I got it wrong so that I can myself learn! =) Is there something I misunderstood in the question? Thanks!