# Copy list items with AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

When I map an object with a List property Automapper by default sets the list property on the destination object to the instance from the source object.

Is there a way for automapper to create a new list and copy the items but not copy the list instance?

I would like the following test to pass:

```
var widget = new Widget
                {
                    Tags = new List<string> {"big", "bright"}
                };

Mapper.Reset();
Mapper.CreateMap<Widget, Widget>();

var widgetCopy = Mapper.Map<Widget, Widget>(widget);

CollectionAssert.Contains(widgetCopy.Tags, "big");
CollectionAssert.Contains(widgetCopy.Tags, "bright");
Assert.AreNotSame(widget.Tags, widgetCopy.Tags);
```

where the widget class looks like:

```
class Widget
{
    public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Currently the last assert fails because the two tags properties point to the same instance of a list. This is a problem when the objects are persisted with NHibernate.

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is deep cloning, something [AutoMapper isn't really designed to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396808/how-to-deep-clone-objects-containing-an-ilist-property-using-automapper).

There are other options available.  See if [ValueInjecter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786761/automapper-recursive) would work for you.

Look at [Deep cloning with ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Deep%20Cloning&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by defining an extension method like this:

```
public static class DeepCopyExtensions
{
    public static List<T> DeepCopy<T>(this List<T> original)
    {
        lock(original) 
            return original.Select(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<T, T>).ToList();
    }

    public static T DeepCopy<T>(this T original)
    {
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<T, T>(original);
    }
}
```

and defining my AutoMapper mapping like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Widget, Widget>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Tags,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Tags.DeepCopy()));
```